# Spring security jwt auth foe more than one User classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Hi I just implement spring security to work with jwt.I have one `User class` for now but I will need to add at least one more and I am planing to made the `User abstract` and create `Employee` and `Admin` classes witch will `inherit the User`.
The problem is when I search for the user is going to the User repository.How to implement this to work with all children classes. I can use generics but at this point where I search for the User try the repository I don't know what type is the user and seems like pointless.

```
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(String.format("User with that username does not exist", username)));

    Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream()
            .map((role) -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
            username,
            user.getPassword(),
            authorities
    );
```

Comment: You dont design principals like that. A user is a user. And it has different GrantedAuthorities, either a GA as a Admin or a GA as a Employee. You should rethink

Comment: I have many additional fields for Employee I want to separate them from Admin but I don't know what is the right approach here.You suggest all the fields to be in on class

Comment: I suggest you have an `id` field in the principal and then you up look what ever you need for that user when it is needed. The principal is used for storing authorization information. A principal is NOT a user object that should have a lot of data about the user. That is a USER object.